# Should you have multiple Mongo connections open or create an API and make calls to that?

Tags: java, mongodb

So say that you have a huge system of servers all needing to interact with a database, should you have a connection to the database open on every single one of those servers or make some sort of API that modifies the database and make calls to that through them instead? 

I'm not sure if having tons of connections opened on a Mongo instance at the same time has any effect on performance but I'm making a scalable game server system that uses Mongo for player storage, so I'd like to know the best way to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple collections in your database, but as far as hosting goes you only need one mongo database open and you can connect to that IP via your various servers.

Comment: So if I had 1,000 connections opened to the same database at the same time there'd be minimal performance impact?

Comment: Yes, mongo is scalable. The IP for the hosted DB never changes so just make sure your various servers are hitting that IP correctly. You also may be interested in looking into Atlas if you want to forego hosting mongo on AWS for instance

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to open a new database connection each time a new user connects, it is highly recomended that your application use some sort of connection pooling.

But if you want, you can say how many connections are allowed on the database, but keep in mind to close the connections for each user, if not, it will remain open connections which it's not recommended.